# How to visualize a neo4j graph

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, neo4j, japplet

I want to visualize a neo4j embedded graph within my JAVA application.
I have read the Max De Marzi's Graph Visualization Blog but I could not find anything in JAVA but only ruby and C++

May you help me to find a guide to install something easy to visualize my graph?
I need just to see nodes and relationships.

P.S.
I do not want to use external programs. 
As a result I do not like: linkurio neoclipse webadmin gephi etc.

Answer (score 14):

There are various options to visualize graph data from Neo4j :

- [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/), [Keylines](http://keylines.com) : javascript libraries for graph visualization
- [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) : open-source solution for graph visualization. It has a plugin
  to easily import Neo4j databases
- [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us) : a solution to search,    explore and visualize graph
  data from Neo4j
- [Neoclipse](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse/blob/master/README.asciidoc) : a tool to view, edit and explore Neo4j databases
- [Neovigator](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neovigator) : a tool to    visually explore graphs
- Neo4j's webadmin : already installed with Neo4j

Here is a table that sum this up and explain the differences : http://linkurio.us/comparative-study/

I also suggest reading Max de Marzi's blog, he is an expert on visualization and Neo4j : http://maxdemarzi.com/

Good luck exploring your data!

Disclaimer : I'm a co-founder of Linkurious