# neo4j, Sorry! Too many neighbours

Tags: neo4j

I have a node that has 39 sub-nodes, when I using neo4j browser, I dbclick this node, and alert "Sorry! Too many neighbours", anyone know how to solve this problem? Is there any better and high performance neo4j graph view tool?

Comment: That's weird, you can also try the old web-ui: `http://localhost:7474/webadmin` and explore the databrowser there, the viz is available from the little icon on the right.

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j has a shell.you can try it. if you running it in the local y can simple run it in your terminal.(ubuntu)

nother thing is neo4j server require high performance..
Try the console.

Comment: I want to see the data structure as a graph view, If use terminal, it will display like mysql?

Comment: @Awakening yes, it will display just pure data like mysql

Answer (score 2):

you can try third party tools such as in this answer: [How to visualize a neo4j graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932256/how-to-visualize-a-neo4j-graph)

or at the main neo4j site there are tutorials and howtos:
http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize